# Utilizar el metodo Next() de la interfaz Iterator

Tags: java

llevo ya unas cuantas horas intentando implementar el metodo next() de la interfaz Iterator, con el objetivo de que devuelva el siguiente número primo

El constructor recibe un argumento que especifica el límite del máximo número primo. Por ejemplo, IteradorPrimos(100) crea un objeto que itera números primos menores o iguales que 100.

```
@Override
public Integer next() {

    Integer contador = limite;
    Integer num = 0;
for(int i=0;i<contador && esPrimo(num)==false;i++)
        num+=i;
        return num;

}
```

Este es uno de los codigos que se me ha ocurrido pero solo me sale el valor que tiene num al principio, o sea , cero. Gracias por las respuestas

Answer (score 0):

Te devuelve siempre 0 porque empiezas a mirar siempre desde 0, tienes que empezar a mirar desde el último primo que has obtenido.

Para hacerlo, tienes que declarar una variable global para guardar el último primo que has devuelto y así seguir calculando los siguientes a partir de este.

public int ultimoPrimo = 0;

```
@Override
public Integer next() {
    int num=0;
    int contador = limite;
    for(int i=ultimoPrimo+1;i<contador && esPrimo(i)==false;i++) //Ponemos ultimoPrimo +1 porque sino nos va a devolver el mismo
        num = num+1;

    return num;
}
```

Al llamar a la función la tendrás que llamar así:

```
ultimoPrimo = next();
```

Answer (score 0):

*Definicion Iterator: Se usa para recorrer colecciones de objetos.*
Una buena de utilizar Iterator, sería esta.

> **1)** Números primos del 1 al 100

```
Integer[] primos = {2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97};
```

> **2)** Creamos lista y añadimos nº primos

```
List lista = Arrays.asList(primos);
```

> **3)** Creamos iterador

```
Iterator i = lista.iterator();
```

> **4)** Recorremos lista

```
while(i.hasNext()){ //Devuelve true si la iteración tiene más elementos
      System.out.print(i.next()+" ");
}
```

Saludos!!